# Why does my Python3 script balk at piping its output to head or tail (sys module)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipe

I have a Python3 script that writes its output to stdout, but it complains when I pipe that output into head or tail. Note in the sample output below that it sort of works, in that `head` is returning the first two lines of output as requested.

```
> ./script.py '../Testdata/*indels.ss' -m 5 | head -2                                                                                              ~/Databases/Avian_genomes/Sandbox/combined
xread
2999 50
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./new.py", line 194, in <module>
    sys.stdout.write(lineout)
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
Exception IOError: IOError(32, 'Broken pipe') in <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'> ignored
```

In contrast, the script has no problem with its output being piped to awk as below.

```
> ./script.py '../Testdata/*indels.ss' -m 5 | awk 'NR < 3 {print $0}'                                                                              ~/Databases/Avian_genomes/Sandbox/combined
xread
2999 50
```

Let me know if you need some code from the script beyond what's contained in the error message. I'm not sure what would be relevant.

Comment: Is there a Unicode character in your third line perhaps?

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15793886

Comment: Actually [IOError: \[Errno 32\] Broken pipe when piping: `prog.py | othercmd`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14207708/1026) seems to be the most active version of this question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
./script.py '../Testdata/*indels.ss' -m 5 | awk 'NR >= 3 {exit} 1'
```

would show the same behavior as `head -2`.

You can turn set the `SIGPIPE` handler to one which quietly kills your program instead:

```
import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGPIPE, signal.SIG_DFL)
```

Comment: but note, this *kills your program*.  If your program is reporting status on something it's doing, adding this code means your program will now silently fail to complete its job when run through head.

Answer (score 11):

I'll cite from [here](http://www.unixguide.net/unix/bash/E2.shtml):

> If a sequence of commands appears in a pipeline, and one of the
>
> reading commands finishes before the writer has finished, the
>
> writer receives a SIGPIPE signal.

That's what `head` does. Your script hasn't finished writing, but `head` is already done, so `stdout` is closed, hence the exception.

Comment: I thought it was probably something like that. Thanks for the explanation and the reference.