# IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe when piping: `prog.py | othercmd`

Tags: python, python-3.x, sigpipe

I have a very simple Python 3 script:

```
f1 = open('a.txt', 'r')
print(f1.readlines())
f2 = open('b.txt', 'r')
print(f2.readlines())
f3 = open('c.txt', 'r')
print(f3.readlines())
f4 = open('d.txt', 'r')
print(f4.readlines())
f1.close()
f2.close()
f3.close()
f4.close()
```

But it always says:

```
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

I saw on the internet all the complicated ways to fix this, but I copied this code directly, so I think that there is something wrong with the code and not Python's SIGPIPE.

I am redirecting the output, so if the above script was named "open.py", then my command to run would be:

```
open.py | othercommand
```

Comment: @squiguy line 2: `print(f1.readlines())`

Comment: You've got two IO operations occurring on line 2: a read from `a.txt` and a write to `stdout`.  Perhaps try splitting those onto separate lines so you can see which operation triggers the exception.  If `stdout` is a pipe and the read end has been closed, then that could account for the `EPIPE` error.

Comment: I can reproduce this error on output (given the right conditions), so I suspect the `print` call is the culprit. @JOHANNES_NYÅTT, can you clarify how you're launching your Python script? Are you redirecting standard output somewhere?

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423225/why-does-my-python3-script-balk-at-piping-its-output-to-head-or-tail-sys-module

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108183/how-to-prevent-sigpipes-or-handle-them-properly

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I haven't reproduced the issue, but perhaps this method would solve it: (writing line by line to `stdout` rather than using `print`)

```
import sys
with open('a.txt', 'r') as f1:
    for line in f1:
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

---

You could catch the broken pipe? This writes the file to `stdout` line by line until the pipe is closed.

```
import sys, errno
try:
    with open('a.txt', 'r') as f1:
        for line in f1:
            sys.stdout.write(line)
except IOError as e:
    if e.errno == errno.EPIPE:
        # Handle error
```

You also need to make sure that `othercommand` is reading from the pipe before it gets too big - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/how-big-is-the-pipe-buffer

Comment: While this is good programming practice, I don't think it has anything to do with the broken pipe error the questioner is getting (which probably has to do with the `print` call, not with reading the files).

Comment: @Blckknght I added a few questions and alternative methods and was hoping for some feedback from the author. If the problem is sending a large quantity of data from an open file directly to the print statement then perhaps one of the alternatives above would fix it.

Comment: (The simplest solutions are often the best - unless there's a particular reason to load a whole file then print it, do it a different way)

Comment: Awesome work in troubleshooting this! While I could take this answer for granted, I could appreciate this only after seeing how the other answers (and my own approach) paled in comparison to your answer.

Comment: You might want also a newline feed: `sys.stdout.write(line + '\n')`

Answer (score 128):

The problem is due to SIGPIPE handling. You can solve this problem using the following code:

```
from signal import signal, SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL
signal(SIGPIPE,SIG_DFL)
```

**Update**: As pointed out in the comments, [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#note-on-sigpipe) already have a good answer.

[See here](http://newbebweb.blogspot.com/2012/02/python-head-ioerror-errno-32-broken.html) for background on this solution. Better answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34718208/catch-broken-pipe-in-python-2-and-python-3).

Comment: This is very dangerous, as I just discovered, because if you ever get a SIGPIPE on a socket (httplib or whatever), your program will just exit without warning or error.

Comment: @DavidBennett, I am sure its application dependent and for your purposes the accepted answer is the right one. There is a much thorough Q&A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108183/how-to-prevent-sigpipes-or-handle-them-properly) for people to go through and make an informed decision. IMO, for command line tools, its probably best to ignore the pipe signal in most cases.

Comment: Perfect! I've made this the default for all python programs by adding these lines to ```/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sitecustomize.py``` (or ```$PYTHONUSERBASE```) BTW @DavidBennett I think``httplib`` should not rely on the default but install it's own signal handler.

Comment: Any way to do this only temporarily?

Comment: @NateGlenn You can save the [existing handler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#signal.getsignal) and restore it later.

Comment: Could someone answer me why people are considering a blogspot article as a better source of truth than [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#note-on-sigpipe) (hint: open the link to see how to fix the broken pipe error properly)? :)

Comment: @YuriiRabeshko Even better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34718208/catch-broken-pipe-in-python-2-and-python-3

Comment: @YuriiRabeshko I tried the official documentation solution to get pygmentize not to throw an error when you exit less before the end of the file, using lesspipe.sh/code2color, and it didn't work. Looking at https://pygments-doc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pygments/cmdline.html, I can see why: it catches all exceptions and prints an error there, so pygmentize itself cannot do anything. The "blog" solution works just fine.

Comment: @YuriiRabeshko because the official documentation is bad. [An answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35761190/1026) demonstrates how complex the actual solution is.

Comment: Hi.  Please update your answer to reflect that the docs you link contradict it.

quote: ```Do not set SIGPIPE’s disposition to SIG_DFL in order to avoid BrokenPipeError. Doing that would cause your program to exit unexpectedly also whenever any socket connection is interrupted while your program is still writing to it.```

Answer (score 125):

To bring information from the many helpful answers together, with some additional information:

- **[Standard Unix signal `SIGPIPE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Error-Codes) is sent to a process *writing* to a [pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_pipe) when there's no process *reading* from the pipe (anymore).**

  - This is not necessarily an *error* condition; some Unix utilities such as `head` *by design* stop reading prematurely from a pipe, once they've received enough data.
  - Therefore, an easy way to provoke this error is to pipe to `head`<sup>[1]</sup>; e.g.:

    - `python -c 'for x in range(10000): print(x)' | head -n 1`
- **By default** - i.e., **if the writing process does not explicitly *trap* `SIGPIPE` - the writing process is simply *terminated*, and its exit code is set to `141`**, which is calculated as `128` (to signal termination by signal in general) + `13` (`SIGPIPE`'s specific signal *number*).
- **However**, by design **Python *itself* traps `SIGPIPE`** and **translates it into a Python `BrokenPipeError` (Python 3) / `IOError` (Python 2)** instance with `errno` value `errno.EPIPE`.

  - Note: If you use a Unix emulation environment *on Windows*, the error may surface differently - see this answer.
- **If a Python *script* does *not* catch the exception**, Python **outputs error message `BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`** (**Python 3**, possibly *twice*, with `Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>` sandwiched in between) / **`IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`** (**Python 2**) and **terminates the script with exit code `1`**<sup>[2]</sup> - this is the symptom Johannes (the OP) saw.

***Windows* considerations (`SIGPIPE` is a Unix-only signal)**

- If your script needs to run directly on Windows too, you may have to conditionally bypass code that references `SIGPIPE`, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66872418/45375).
- If your script runs in a *Unix subsystem* on Windows, the `SIGPIPE` signal may surface *differently* than on Unix - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66874837/45375).

---

There are two ways to solve this problem:

**Generally, it is *not* advisable to *silence* this exception**, as it may signal a severe error condition, depending on your script's purpose, such as the receiving end of a network socket unexpectedly closing.

- However, **if your script is a *command-line utility***, where quiet termination may not only be acceptable but *preferred* so as to play nicely with the standard `head` utility, for instance, you can **abort *quietly*** as follows, using [`signal.signal()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.signal) to install the platform's *default signal handler* (which behaves as described above), as also shown in [akhan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16865106/45375) (works in both Python 3 and 2):

```
# ONLY SUITABLE FOR COMMAND-LINE UTILITIES

# Install the default signal handler.
from signal import signal, SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL)

# Start printing many lines.
# If this gets interrupted with SIGPIPE, 
# the script aborts quietly, and the process exit code is set to
# 141 (128 + SIGPIPE)
for x in range(10000): print(x)
```

- Otherwise, if you want **to handle the SIGPIPE-triggered exception yourself** (works in both Python 3 and 2, adapted from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#note-on-sigpipe)):

```
import sys, os, errno

try:

  # Start printing many lines.
  for x in range(10000): print(x)

  # IMPORTANT: Flush stdout here, to ensure that the 
  # SIGPIPE-triggered exception can be caught.
  sys.stdout.flush()

except IOError as e: 
  # Note: Python 3 has the more specific BrokenPipeError,
  #       but this way the code works in Python 2 too.
  if e.errno != errno.EPIPE: raise e # Unrelated error, re-throw.

  # Python flushes standard streams on exit; redirect remaining output
  # to devnull to avoid another BrokenPipeError at shutdown
  devnull = os.open(os.devnull, os.O_WRONLY)
  os.dup2(devnull, sys.stdout.fileno())

  # ... perform other handling.
  # Note: You can't write to stdout here.
  #       (print() and sys.stdout.write won't work)
  #       However, sys.stderr.write() can be used.
  sys.stderr.write("SIGPIPE received, terminating.\n")

  # Finally, exit with an exit code of choice.
  sys.exit(141)
```

---

<sup>[1] Note that in `bash` you will by default only see `head`'s exit code - which is `0` - reflected in `$?` afterwards. Use `echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]}` to see Python's exit code.</sup>

<sup>[2] Curiously, on macOS 10.15.7 (Catalina), with Python 3.9.2 (but not 2.x), I see exit code `120`, but the docs say `1`, and that's what I also see on Linux.</sup>

Answer (score 31):

A "Broken Pipe" error occurs when you try to write to a pipe that has been closed on the other end. Since the code you've shown doesn't involve any pipes directly, I suspect you're doing something outside of Python to redirect the standard output of the Python interpreter to somewhere else. This could happen if you're running a script like this:

```
python foo.py | someothercommand
```

The issue you have is that `someothercommand` is exiting without reading everything available on its standard input. This causes your write (via `print`) to fail at some point.

I was able to reproduce the error with the following command on a Linux system:

```
python -c 'for i in range(1000): print i' | less
```

If I close the `less` pager without scrolling through all of its input (1000 lines), Python exits with the same `IOError` you have reported.

Comment: Yes, this is true, but how do I fix it?

Comment: @JOHANNES_NYÅTT: It's probably not something that you can fix from within your Python program. Instead, you need to find out why the other program is exiting and fix that (either by changing its code, if you can, or by calling it differently). We might be able to help, but you'll need to tell us what `othercommand` is, and what you expect it to do with the input you're sending it.

Comment: please let me know how to fix it.

Comment: For some reason when the file is a few kb it works, but it gives this error when the file is above 1 mb

Comment: @JOHANNES_NYÅTT: It may work for small files because of the buffering provided by pipes on most Unix-like systems. If you can write the whole contents of the files into the buffer, it doesn't raise an error if the other program never reads that data. However, if the write blocks (because the buffer is full), then it will fail when the other program quits. To say again: What is the other command? We can't help you any more with only the Python code (since it's not the part that's doing the wrong thing).

Comment: @JOHANNES_NYÅTT That's because your pipe is probably only around 64kB - if you try to write too much to it and other process isn't reading it then it'll throw an error. I've shown how to catch the error in my last example. Is there anything else you would like?

Comment: I got this problem when piping to head... exception after ten lines of output. Quite logical, but still unexpected :)

Comment: "That's because your pipe is probably only around 64kB - if you try to write too much to it and other process isn't reading it then it'll throw an error." Ref that comment I don't think it's true - the next write will simply block until the reader empties out [some of] the buffer by reading it.

Comment: @Blckknght: Good info in general, but re "_fix_ that: and "the part that's doing the _wrong_ thing": a `SIGPIPE` signal does not necessarily indicate an _error_ condition; some Unix utilities, notably `head`, _by design, during normal operation_ close the pipe early, once they've read as much data as _they_ needed.

Answer (score 22):

I feel obliged to point out that the method using

```
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL)
```

is indeed **dangerous** (as already suggested by David Bennet in the comments) and in my case led to platform-dependent funny business when combined with `multiprocessing.Manager` (because the standard library relies on BrokenPipeError being raised in several places). To make a long and painful story short, this is how I fixed it:

First, you need to catch the `IOError` (Python 2) or `BrokenPipeError` (Python 3). Depending on your program you can try to exit early at that point or just ignore the exception:

```
from errno import EPIPE

try:
    broken_pipe_exception = BrokenPipeError
except NameError:  # Python 2
    broken_pipe_exception = IOError

try:
    YOUR CODE GOES HERE
except broken_pipe_exception as exc:
    if broken_pipe_exception == IOError:
        if exc.errno != EPIPE:
            raise
```

However, this isn't enough. Python 3 may still print a message like this:

```
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Unfortunately getting rid of that message is not straightforward, but I finally found http://bugs.python.org/issue11380 where Robert Collins suggests this workaround that I turned into a decorator you can wrap your main function with (yes, that's some crazy indentation):

```
from functools import wraps
from sys import exit, stderr, stdout
from traceback import print_exc


def suppress_broken_pipe_msg(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        except SystemExit:
            raise
        except:
            print_exc()
            exit(1)
        finally:
            try:
                stdout.flush()
            finally:
                try:
                    stdout.close()
                finally:
                    try:
                        stderr.flush()
                    finally:
                        stderr.close()
    return wrapper


@suppress_broken_pipe_msg
def main():
    YOUR CODE GOES HERE
```

Comment: This didn't seem to fix it for me.

Comment: It worked for me after I added except BrokenPipeError: pass in the supress_broken_pipe_msg function

Comment: Yeah, this requires BOTH the `suppress_broken_pipe_msg` bit to silence the `Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper` message and the first `except broken_pipe_exception` code block to actually handle the broken pipe exception in a Python 2/3 compatible way.

Comment: And even this [doesn't work on Windows, which raises an OSError instead of BrokenPipeError](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32555219/1026).

Answer (score 4):

I know this is not the "proper" way to do it, but if you are simply interested in getting rid of the error message, you could try this workaround:

```
python your_python_code.py 2> /dev/null | other_command
```

Comment: `python your_python_code.py | tee /dev/null | other_command` — also works. But I cannot understand why it works with `stderr`.

Comment: Would that send the whole output to `/dev/null`?

Answer (score 3):

The top answer (`if e.errno == errno.EPIPE:`) here didn't really work for me.  I got:

```
AttributeError: 'BrokenPipeError' object has no attribute 'EPIPE'
```

However, this ought to work if all you care about is ignoring broken pipes on specific writes.  I think it's safer than trapping SIGPIPE:

```
try:
    # writing, flushing, whatever goes here
except BrokenPipeError:
    exit( 0 )
```

You obviously have to make a decision as to whether your code is really, truly done if you hit the broken pipe, but for most purposes I think that's usually going to be true.  (Don't forget to close file handles, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the exact cause of the issue, it might help to set an environment variable `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1`, which forces the stdout and stderr streams to be unbuffered. See: https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u

So, your command

```
open.py | othercommand
```

becomes:

```
PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 open.py | othercommand
```

Example:

```
$ python3 -m http.server | tee -a access.log
^CException ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

$ PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 python3 -m http.server | tee -a access.log
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 (http://0.0.0.0:8000/) ...
^C
$
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also occur if the read end of the output from your script dies prematurely

ie   open.py | otherCommand

if otherCommand exits   and open.py tries to write to stdout

I had a bad gawk script that did this lovely to me.

Comment: It's not about the process reading from the pipe _dying_, necessarily: some Unix utilities, notably `head`, _by design, during normal operation_ close the pipe early, once they've read as much data as _they_ needed. Most CLIs simply defer to the system for its default behavior: quietly terminating the reading process and reporting exit code `141` (which, in a shell, isn't readily apparent, because a pipeline's _last_ command determines the overall exit code). _Python_'s default behavior, unfortunately, is to die _noisily_.

Answer (score -3):

Closes should be done in reverse order of the opens.

Comment: While that is good practice in general, not doing is not a problem in itself and doesn't explain the OP's symptoms.