# "OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument" on Windows with print() and output piped

Tags: python, windows, msysgit, wc

I've come across some (to me) weird behaviour when piping the output of a Python script into `wc` with invalid arguments.

```
λ python test.py
Hello!
λ python test.py | wc -li
wc: unknown option -- i
Try 'wc --help' for more information.
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

What is happening here?

My configuration is

- Windows 10
- Cmder
- msysgit 2.5.1.windows.1

Comment: @achampion Right, it doesn't have the option. And that's the reason why the error occurs in Python. I want to know what exactly happens that this `OSError` is caused and why it has to do with an invalid argument passed to `wc`.

Comment: `wc` is exiting when it sees an invalid option which closes the pipe, python continues to write to the pipe and fails. Fortunately, I get a more reasonable error message for the same exception (Mac OSX): `BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`.

Comment: Don't put stock in the significance of `EINVAL`. The CRT has to map thousands of Win32 error codes to just about 40 `errno` values. Probably the Win32 error here is `ERROR_NO_DATA` because the pipe is being closed. In principle I think this should map to  `EPIPE` (broken pipe), but for some reason the CRT uses the default value of `EINVAL` (invalid argument).

Answer (score 3):

As [@AChampion noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32555219/python-print-and-wc-with-invalid-argument-leads-to-oserror#comment52966580_32555219), this is the Windows version of [IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe when piping: `prog.py | othercmd`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207708/ioerror-errno-32-broken-pipe-when-piping-prog-py-othercmd/35761190#35761190) with the added caveat that Python fails to raise the correct exception (i.e. `BrokenPipeError`).

There's [issue 35754](https://bugs.python.org/issue35754) *"[Windows] I/O on a broken pipe may raise an EINVAL OSError instead of BrokenPipeError"* Python's bug tracker.

Until it's fixed, I don't see a general way to handle it.

[How to duplicate sys.stdout to a log file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/616645/1026) helps solve this for Python-based output (printing via `sys.stdout`):

```
class IgnoreBrokenPipe(object):
    def __init__(self, stream):
        self.stream = stream
        def ignore_einval(fn):
            from functools import wraps
            @wraps(fn)
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                try:
                    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
                except OSError as exc:
                    if exc.errno != 22:
                        raise exc
                    else:  # mimicking the default SIGPIPE behavior on Windows
                        sys.exit(1)
            return wrapper

        self.write = ignore_einval(lambda data: self.stream.write(data))
        self.flush = ignore_einval(lambda: self.stream.flush())

import sys
sys.stdout = IgnoreBrokenPipe(sys.stdout)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem while using the gauge test framework.

The problem was, after creating a `subprocess.Popen` with `stdout` and `stderr` parameters set to `subprocess.PIPE` for test suite (I wanted to capture all output from that process) and an attempt to print something to `sys.stderr` in tested code, "OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument" has been raised.