# Piping to head results in broken pipe in shell script called from python

Tags: python, bash, shell, pipe, head

I have a command I would to run to generate random string:

```
var=`< /dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9 | head -c8`
```

When I run this command in interactive bash session I get absolutely no errors. But when I put this command into script and run it as a script I get Broken pipe error indicated by tr. I've read several related topics but still has no answer why script and interactive behavior is different and is there a way to control it with shell options or with something else?

**Edit I:**

In regards to comments given I found that indicating broken pipe errors can be controlled via:

```
 trap - SIGPIPE # to ignore errors
```

and

```
 trap "" SIGPIPE # to display errors
```

**Edit II:**

Well, I've provided incorrect information about reproduction conditions. Finally it seems that problem caused with the python wrapper that called the script with the os.system():

```
 python -c "import os; os.system('sh -c \"< /dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9 | head -c8\"')"
```

Line given produces broken pipe errors independently of used OS.

**Edit III:**

This topic has been discussed here:
https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-September/056341.html

Comment: Sounds like the issue being discussed [here](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/issues/494) and in the referenced issue. (shellcheck isn't involved here it just happens to be a discussion of this exact problem and discussion about having shellcheck, which is a great tool, warning about exactly this sort of thing.)

Comment: Works perfectly under Cygwin/bash-4.1.10(4)... (Set up  your line plus an `echo $var` in a script, nothing more except `#!/bin/sh`.)

Comment: Are you trapping SIGPIPE in the script?

Comment: `trap - pipe` == reset sigpipe to its default disposition (=kill target); `trap '' pipe` == set the disposition of sigpipe to `SIG_IGN`

Comment: `tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9` should apparently be `tr -dc _A-Za-z0-9`. I get "invalid byte sequence" unless I prefix the repro command line with `LC_ALL=C` (the bytes from `urandom` are usually not valid UTF-8, which trips `tr` and generally most character-processing utilities in UTF-8 locales).

Comment: Also for the record, the repro command line simply hangs for me on Mac OS High Sierra (10.13)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If one of the parent processes traps `sigpipe`, then the pipeline will inherit the `ignore` signal disposition, which will cause this problem you're experiencing.

This can be (safely) reproduced with:

```
( trap '' pipe; var=`< /dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9 | head -c8` )
```

Normally, the `head -c8` command will be done pretty soon at which point its `stdin` is closed. Since it's `stdin` is a pipe connected to the `stdout` of `tr`, it now no longer makes sense for `tr` to write to its `stdout`. Once it tries to, the system will kill it with `SIGPIPE`.
Unless `tr` ignores this signal or has inherited the `ignore` (`SIG_IGN`) disposition for this signal from its parent. Then a `write` to `tr`'s broken `stdout` will simply cause a regular error and set `errno` to `EPIPE` at which point `tr` will most likely stringify and outputs this error to its `stderr` and exit.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30091579/456550) provides a good summary of the problem with piping from Python to `head`, and shows some workarounds.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30091579/456550

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that `head` reads the specified (or default) number of lines from the input stream, prints them, and then quits. So an upstream program in a pipe that is still writing finds the output stream closed. In my opinion, this is a limitation in the design of `head` itself. You can instead use `sed`, which reads the whole stream: `sed -n "1,10p"`is equivalent to `head -n10`.

Comment: It's particularly subtle because you don't get SIGPIPE error if the input stream is truncated but too small to raise the error (I guess smaller than some buffer). On my system I get exit codes "0 0" with `seq 1 1000 | head && echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}` but I get codes "141 0" with `seq 1 10000 | head && echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}` even if in both case the output of `seq` is truncated.