# Optimizing django and mysql for peak requirement

Tags: python, mysql, django

I've coded the backend of my recently launched mobile application using django 1.9, and the database I've used is MySQL. I'm about to start a large promotional campaign so trying to gear up the backend for the same.

One issue that I'm constantly facing is that when I fire just around 100 threads in a span of 10 seconds via Apache Jmeter, a large number (~60) of them do not get served. Django server logs look like this:

```
[24/Aug/2016 22:43:01] "GET /my/api/ HTTP/1.0" 200 78547 
[24/Aug/2016 22:43:01] "GET /my/api/ HTTP/1.0" 200 78547
- Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 53582)
- Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 53597) 
[24/Aug/2016 22:43:01] "GET /my/api/ HTTP/1.0" 200 78547
- Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 53551)
```

What exactly does the broken pipe signify? How do I get around this?

Comment: "What more should I do to be ready for a large number of hits?" Close: Too broad. "Broken pipe... what does this mean and how do I fix it?" Answerable, would upvote. Please revise your question to be _one question_. I recommend the latter. ;)

Comment: thought so too. edited. :)

Comment: Are you testing jMeter with nginx load balancing in front or are you just hitting the Django debug server?

Comment: I'm using nginx to route requests to my Django debug server. Does that make a difference here?

Comment: Yes, a quite large one. The built-in webserver is not meant to be performance ready so there's no point load-testing it. Usually you want nginx (or something like it but it's quite good and scaleable) load-balancing in front of several uwsgi servers to run Django at scale.

Answer (score 0):

The usual technique for scaling into make multiple instances (different computers) and then apply static file caching and load balancing with tools like [NGinx](https://www.nginx.com/), [Varnish](https://varnish-cache.org/), and [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/).

Broken pipes are explained in this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30091579/1001643