# Piping explicit conda list

Tags: python, pipe, conda

I need to pipe some conda commands:

```
$ conda list --export | head -n 3
# This file may be used to create an environment using:
# $ conda create --name <env> --file <this file>
# platform: linux-64
```

This works fine. However piping the explicit list fails:

```
$ conda list --explicit | head -n 3
# This file may be used to create an environment using:
# $ conda create --name <env> --file <this file>
# platform: linux-64
An unexpected error has occurred.
Please consider posting the following information to the
conda GitHub issue tracker at:

    https://github.com/conda/conda/issues



Current conda install:

               platform : linux-64
          conda version : 4.2.12
       conda is private : False
      conda-env version : 4.2.12
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 2.7.12.final.0
       requests version : 2.11.1
       root environment : /home/me/miniconda3  (writable)
    default environment : /home/me/miniconda3
       envs directories : /home/me/miniconda3/envs
          package cache : /home/me/miniconda3/pkgs
           channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
            config file : None
           offline mode : False



`$ /home/me/miniconda3/bin/conda list --explicit`
```

The traceback is (sorry, it wont allow me to put it inside code tags...):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):    
File "/home/me/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 479, in conda_exception_handler
return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/me/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 145, in _main
  exit_code = args.func(args, p)

File "/home/me/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main_list.py", line 213, in execute
  print_explicit(prefix, args.md5)

File "/home/me/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main_list.py", line 190, in print_explicit
  print(url + ('#%s' % md5 if add_md5 and md5 else ''))

IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

That's probably a bug right? Without piping it works fine.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on my Ubuntu 16.04 system with Python 3. What OS are you using?

Comment: I tried this on mac osx. Ill try with a linux

Comment: But your `conda info` shows `linux-64`? FWIW, I can't reproduce this on OS X either, but again, its Miniconda 3

Comment: Sorry I got it wrong.. You are right I executed the command on Linux. Then I used those information to install the conda packages on mac that's how I got confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The broken pipe is occurring because `head` is closing the output stream once it gets the 3 lines that it has been instructed to show. You'll notice that you get those three lines in your output. The next time that conda tries to print, it cannot because `head` has closed the pipe. That is what is causing this exception. This is not a problem with conda. Have a look here for further information regarding broken pipe exceptions in python: [IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe: Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207708/ioerror-errno-32-broken-pipe-python)

Now for a potential work around:

`$ conda list --explicit > /tmp/conda-explicit-output && head -n 15 /tmp/conda-explicit-output && rm /tmp/conda-explicit-output`

Yeah it's pretty ugly, but it will probably get the job done.

Comment: I guess you solved it! So it's not a piping issue generally speaking. If I do `$ conda list --explicit | wc -l` I get `297`. So now: `$ conda list --explicit | head -n 297` returns the correct results. Actually I used `head` for testing purposes, I don't need it per se. So I don't need the "ugly" piece of code ;) THanks!