# Trying to rotate the text by 90

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

[image]

I am using Tkinter and [CanvasPlus](https://pypi.org/project/canvasplus/) library to rotate the text by 90 degrees but I am not able to rotate.
This is the code I am trying

```
self.circle = self.canvas.create_circle(0, 0, self.circle_radius, fill=self.bg_color, 
                                        outline="green", width=3)

self.label_ready_for_cooking = self.canvas.create_label(0, 0, font=("Arial", 28),
                                                        fg="white", bg=self.bg_color, 
                                                        text="READY\nFOR", anchor="be")

self.canvas.rotate(self.label_ready_for_cooking, 10, 10, 90, unit="deg")
```

The image is showing but I am not able to rotate the image.
How can I do this?

Comment: Not sure what image you are talking about, nor what text. Please [edit] your question and clarify. Added a screenshot of the results you are currently getting, too, if possible.

Comment: Not sure if this is going to be helpful but: Why don't you use the PIL library? It supports all kinds of image manipulations and the images can be placed on the canvas.

Comment: I just went through the [wiki](https://github.com/Luke-zhang-04/CanvasPlus/wiki/Widget-Windows#create_label), if I haven't missed, I don't think you can use `rotate` on [Widget Windows](https://github.com/Luke-zhang-04/CanvasPlus/wiki/Widget-Windows)

Comment: From the canonical tcl/tk documentation: _"Individual items may be moved or scaled using widget commands described below, **but they may not be rotated**."_

Comment: I added the image. I want this type image.

Comment: I used the PIL library but when I am using it is throwing a Broken error.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to the [GitHub Wiki](https://github.com/Luke-zhang-04/CanvasPlus/wiki) of this library

> [CanvasPlus.rotate()](https://github.com/Luke-zhang-04/CanvasPlus/wiki/rotate()) There's no easy way to rotate something in tkinter. Usually, there's a lot of math and trig that is put into it. This method uses complex numbers to rotate a polygon clockwise in radians or degrees.

Basically all the transformations are only applicable to polygons and not any of the [Widget Windows](https://github.com/Luke-zhang-04/CanvasPlus/wiki/Widget-Windows).

**UPDATE**

You could achieve what you are looking for by using the `angle` parameter of `create_text` in the default `Canvas` widget of `tkinter`.

Try this

```py
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

canvas=Canvas()
canvas.pack()

canvas.create_text(100,100,text='Rotated Text',angle=90)

root.mainloop()
```

> Note that angle option is available in tk 8.6.x. @[acw1668](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5317403/acw1668)

Comment: when I am using this function it is throwing a broken pipe error.

Comment: @harshit You can not use any transformation methods (like `rotate`) on a `create_label` instance or any widget for that matter, you can only use it on polygons like `create_rectangle`.  What you are trying to achieve is not possible with this lib.

Comment: @harshit I have updated my answer with a possible solution

Comment: Note that `angle` option is available in tk 8.6.x.

Comment: By this method, it is throwing broken pipe error.

Comment: @harshit You might want to look into [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207708/ioerror-errno-32-broken-pipe-python). It's not a problem related to this method or PIL as you mentioned in the comments.