# problem on sys.stdout used with the buffer

Tags: python, buffer, stdout

on an old code on github that I used to use, the devs seems to plan a python 3 version but it seem that something doesn't work anymore. Here the piece of code (don't know if it's enought) :

```
# ---------
# Specifics
# ---------

if is_py2:
    if is_py26:
        from logging import Handler

        class NullHandler(Handler):
            def emit(self, record):
                pass

        from ordereddict import OrderedDict
    else:
        from logging import NullHandler
        from collections import OrderedDict

    from io import StringIO

    def to_char(string):
        if len(string) == 0:
            return bytes('')
        return bytes(string[0])

    bytes = str
    str = str
    stdout = sys.stdout
    xrange = xrange


elif is_py3:
    from logging import NullHandler
    from collections import OrderedDict
    from io import StringIO

    def to_char(string):
        if len(string) == 0:
            return str('')
        return str(string[0])

    str = str
    bytes = bytes
    stdout = sys.stdout.buffer
    xrange = range
```

And the error I get on Spyder trying to use it :

```
  File ~/miniconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spyder_kernels/py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File ~/miniconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pylink/sanstitre1.py:9
    from pyvantagepro import VantagePro2

  File ~/miniconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyvantagepro/__init__.py:13
    from .logger import LOGGER, active_logger

  File ~/miniconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyvantagepro/logger.py:14
    from .compat import NullHandler

  File ~/miniconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyvantagepro/compat.py:91
    stdout = sys.stdout.buffer

AttributeError: 'TTYOutStream' object has no attribute 'buffer'
```

I tried to figure it out but I'm not good enought in python ... How to resolve this error ? If I didn't put enought code I'll make a new topic with all link and code.

Comment: maybe you should use only `stdout = sys.stdout`?

Comment: documentation for [sys.stdout](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout) has notes that sometimes it can be assigned to stream and it may have `.buffer` but normally it doesn't have `.buffer`. So maybe it would be better to use `sys.stdout` instead of `sys.stdout.buffer`

Comment: If I remove .buffer, the error evolve in "BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe". Just can't figure it out. But maybe it's two different errors, that's an old code.

Comment: for sure it different problem. You would have to show full error message in question (maybe on new page).

Comment: if you use it for piping command then it may need to remove `signal` assigned by `Python` and use default signal: [python - IOError: Errno 32: Broken pipe when piping: prog.py | othercmd - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207708/ioerror-errno-32-broken-pipe-when-piping-prog-py-othercmd)