# How to avoid a Broken Pipe error when printing a large amount of formatted data?

Tags: python, format, string-formatting, ioerror, broken-pipe

I am trying to print a list of tuples formatted in my `stdout`. For this, I use the [str.format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting) method. Everything works fine, but when I pipe the output to see the
first lines using the `head` command a `IOError` occurs.

Here is my code:

```
# creating the data
data = []$
for i in range(0,  1000):                                            
  pid = 'pid%d' % i
  uid = 'uid%d' % i
  pname = 'pname%d' % i
  data.append( (pid, uid, pname) )

# find max leghed string for each field
pids, uids, pnames = zip(*data)
max_pid = len("%s" % max( pids) )
max_uid = len("%s" % max( uids) )
max_pname = len("%s" % max( pnames) )

# my template for the formatted strings
template = "{0:%d}\t{1:%d}\t{2:%d}" % (max_pid, max_uid, max_pname)

# print the formatted output to stdout
for pid, uid, pname in data:
  print template.format(pid, uid, pname)
```

And here is the error I get after running the command: `python myscript.py | head`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lala.py", line 16, in <module>
    print template.format(pid, uid, pname)
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Can anyone help me on this?

I tried to put `print` in a `try-except` block to handle the error,
but after that there was another message in the console:

```
close failed in file object destructor:
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
```

I also tried to flush immediately the data through a two consecutive
`sys.stdout.write` and `sys.stdout.flush` calls, but nothing happend..

Comment: This happens because `head` *closes* `stdout`, causing `print` to try and write to a closed file. What would you like to happen instead?

Comment: Ok, thank you! I would like to avoid the printing of such messages in the console. I want to use a variation of this code to a command line tool.

Comment: This question is a possible duplicate; see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423225/why-does-my-python3-script-balk-at-piping-its-output-to-head-or-tail-sys-module

Comment: Duplicate of: [IOError: \[Errno 32\] Broken pipe when piping: \`prog.py | othercmd\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207708/ioerror-errno-32-broken-pipe-when-piping-prog-py-othercmd)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`head` reads from `stdout` then *closes* it. This causes `print` to fail, internally it writes to `sys.stdout`, now closed.

You can simply *catch* the `IOError` and exit silently:

```
try:
    for pid, uid, pname in data:
        print template.format(pid, uid, pname)
except IOError:
    # stdout is closed, no point in continuing
    # Attempt to close them explicitly to prevent cleanup problems:
    try:
        sys.stdout.close()
    except IOError:
        pass
    try:
        sys.stderr.close()
    except IOError:
        pass
```

Comment: ok in this simple program this works, but in the command line tool sometimes works and sometimes occurs again this message:
`close failed in file object destructor:
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr`

Comment: Haha! I found it too in some answer at stackoverflow! i tried it but it doesn't work! It seems that there is a race condition.. But I cannot figure out how to solve it..

Comment: ok I found it! It needs just an addition to your answer. Just put a `sys.stdout.flush()` right after the print statement!! But the error is what you described! I also noticed that for some reason if I put the flush out of the loop it works too.. Anyway. thank you! :)

Comment: @ThanasisPetsas: The flush can be affected by the close too.

Comment: I used the first version of your answer with the `flush` after the `print` and everything works great!

Comment: Glad to have been of help then. :-)  The flush may work for you because when using pipes python uses a regular file buffer instead of a line buffer, and flushing helps get your data out line by line in that case.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have come across you answers many times and they have helped me! :)

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work in Python 3.   Python 3 raises BrokenPipeError, but _io.TextIOWrapper catches it and emits it as a warning.  So the failure isn't quite as bad but still ugly and annoying, and there's no way I can see yet to suppress it.

Comment: Warnings can be silenced with the `warnings` module; or is this not one of those?

Answer (score 2):

The behavior you are seeing is linked to the buffered output implementation in Python3. The problem can be avoided using the -u option or setting environmental variable PYTHONUNBUFFERED=x. See the man pages for more information on -u.

```
$ python2.7 testprint.py | echo

Exc: <type 'exceptions.IOError'>
$ python3.5 testprint.py | echo

Exc: <class 'BrokenPipeError'>
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
$ python3.5 -u testprint.py | echo

Exc: <class 'BrokenPipeError'>
$ export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=x
$ python3.5 testprint.py | echo

Exc: <class 'BrokenPipeError'>
```

Comment: Yup, but I had this problem in Python2.7. I don't use Python3.

Answer (score 2):

In general, I try to catch the most specific error I can get away with. In this case it is `BrokenPipeError`:

```
try:
    # I usually call a function here that generates all my output:
    for pid, uid, pname in data:
        print template.format(pid, uid, pname)
except BrokenPipeError as e:
    pass  # Ignore. Something like head is truncating output.
finally:
    sys.stderr.close()
```

If this is at the end of execution, I find I only need to close `sys.stderr`. If I don't close `sys.stderr`, I'll get a BrokenPipeError but without a stack trace.

This seems to be the minimum fix for writing tools that output to pipelines.

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem with Python3 and debug logging piped into head as well.  If your script talks to the network or does file IO, simply dropping IOError's is not a good solution.  Despite mentions here, I was not able to catch BrokenPipeError for some reason.

Found a blog post talking about restoring the default signal handler for sigpipe: http://newbebweb.blogspot.com/2012/02/python-head-ioerror-errno-32-broken.html

In short, you add the following to your script before the bulk of the output:

```
if log.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG):  # optional
    # set default handler to no-op
    from signal import signal, SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL
    signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL)
```

This seems to happen with head, but not other programs such as grep---as mentioned head closes stdout.  If you don't use head with the script often, it may not be worth worrying about.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the explanation and the article!