# Sourcing output of python script fails with broken pipe exception

Tags: python, bash, macos, python-3.x

I'm trying to have the output of a python script be sourceable. i.e. I'd like to be able to run:

```
$ source <(python example.py)
```

It ALWAYS fails with the same issue:

```
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Here is example.py:

```
print("export ENV_VAR=abc")
```

Is there any way around this? I've attempted to try and catch the exception (BrokenPipeError) but it doesn't seem to work. The exception seems to prevent the sourcing from working since

```
$ echo $ENV_VAR
```

gives me nothing

Comment: This could be a [open issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue11380,#msg153320) in Python

Comment: Your example works fine in my shell (bash on Cygwin).

Comment: I should mention this is python 3.6 on macOS

Comment: On macOS, the same happens with Python 2.7. On Linux, it works.

Comment: This sounds like it might be a buffering issue. Does adding `sys.stdout.flush()` as the very last line of `example.py` make a difference? I was able to mock up something that reproduced  this behaviour with named pipes in Linux, and flushing solved the problem.

Comment: I did try flushing `stdout` and it did not solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `eval` or `export` could be used to get the variables from a `Python` script into the current `Bash` environment:

```
export $( python example.py )
echo $ENV_VAR
```

...or...

```
eval $( python example.py )
echo $ENV_VAR
```

There might be a better way to handle this, although both should output "abc".

Comment: you can simply use `$(python example.py)` and it does work, but for my use case, that isn't good enough. I'd like to have the script give output so if you run it incorrectly (i.e. missing the `source`) it can print output so you know you need to run it a different way. (i.e. `print("# You need to run the command like so ....")`). If you have something like that with the `$()` method, it wont work. It should/would work with `source <(...)`

Comment: Maybe report the behavior as a bug perhaps, since it doesn’t seem correct as of now.

Answer (score 0):

You can [fix it in the python script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69833114/5954238) or by sending the output of the python script to a program that does not freak out when its stdout is closed.

```sh
source <(python example.py | tee -p /dev/null)
```

---

*Side note: I could not get `source` to reproduce the error described, but I was able to replicate the problem using `echo`*