# How to prevent BrokenPipeError when grepping aws logs tail output?

Tags: bash, aws-cli

Im writing an bash script to help the logging of our system running at AWS.

Simplified version of the command it runs in the end is `aws logs tail | grep "term"`. Everything works fine but when I'm closing the log stream with ctrl + c, i get the following error:

```
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Can i prevent that from happening, or is it something that should be caught in the `aws logs` script?

Comment: It is something that should be caught in the aws logs script.

Answer (score 0):

It is a misfeature in Python which `aws` is [expected to handle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69833114/5954238). However, if you simply want the error to not be shown, you can do this:

```
 aws logs tail | tee -p /dev/null | grep "term"
```