# BrokenPipeError when writing to sys.stdout and a Linux pipe

Tags: python, pipe

I want to write to sys.stdout in a way that the output can be 'piped' in Linux (e.g. with `| head`). I thought I was being clever with the following code: by specifying `sys.stdout` as the file, I can let my program write to STDOUT or a file depending on the input flag.

```py
def write(outfile: str, data: str):
    try:
        fp = sys.stdout  # already an open descriptor
        if outfile:  # user wants to write to file
            fp = open(outfile, "w+")
            
        fp.write(data)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Could not write to file", e)
```

This works fine.
However, when I decide to run the command with a pipe:

`python3 command.py | head`

I get a BrokenPipeError. Why is this?

Comment: How many lines of output is your program trying to write?

Comment: It's trying to write 13001 lines :) It writes them just fine to the terminal if I'm not using `| head`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent BrokenPipeError when doing a flush in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26692284/how-to-prevent-brokenpipeerror-when-doing-a-flush-in-python)

Comment: See also https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#note-on-sigpipe